# Unable to upgrade Symfony 5.4 to 6.2 due to symfony package conflicts

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I'm trying to upgrade a Symfony project from version 4.4 to version 6.2 using php 8.2.

I can successfully upgrade to version 5.4 by upgrading all third party packages, and symfony packages to v5.4.

My issue comes when I try to upgrade from v5.4 to v6.2.

First off, I change all 5.4 to 6.2 in `composer.json` and then do `composer update "symfony/*" --with-all-dependencies` as mentionned in the official documentation.

But I get multiple conflicts with symfony packages and all conflict messages end by this phrase

> "but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another
> require"

So in the end I have no idea what's the starting point of the conflicts.

Below the stack trace I get with `composer update "symfony/*" --with-all-dependencies`

```
Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires symfony/framework-bundle 6.2.*, found symfony/framework-bundle[v6.2.0, ..., v6.2.10] but these were not loaded, likely because it conf
licts with another require.
  Problem 2
    - doctrine/doctrine-bundle is locked to version 2.6.4 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - doctrine/doctrine-bundle 2.6.4 requires symfony/config ^4.4.3|^5.0|^6.0 -> found symfony/config[v4.4.3, ..., v4.4.44, v5.0.0, ..., v5.4.21, v6.0.0, ..., v6.2.7] b
ut these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
  Problem 3
    - doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle is locked to version 3.2.2 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle 3.2.2 requires symfony/framework-bundle ~3.4|~4.0|~5.0|~6.0 -> found symfony/framework-bundle[v3.4.0, ..., v3.4.47, v4.0.0, ..
., v4.4.49, v5.0.0, ..., v5.4.22, v6.0.0, ..., v6.2.10] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
  Problem 4
    - nelmio/cors-bundle is locked to version 2.3.1 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - nelmio/cors-bundle 2.3.1 requires symfony/framework-bundle ^4.4 || ^5.4 || ^6.0 -> found symfony/framework-bundle[v4.4.0, ..., v4.4.49, v5.4.0, ..., v5.4.22, v6.0
.0, ..., v6.2.10] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
  Problem 5
    - sensio/framework-extra-bundle is locked to version v5.6.1 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - sensio/framework-extra-bundle v5.6.1 requires symfony/config ^4.4|^5.0 -> found symfony/config[v4.4.0, ..., v4.4.44, v5.0.0, ..., v5.4.21] but these were not load
ed, likely because it conflicts with another require.
  Problem 6
    - Root composer.json requires symfony/twig-bundle 6.2.* -> satisfiable by symfony/twig-bundle[v6.2.0, ..., v6.2.7].
    - symfony/twig-bundle[v6.2.0, ..., v6.2.7] require symfony/config ^6.1 -> found symfony/config[v6.1.0, ..., v6.2.7] but these were not loaded, likely because it con
flicts with another require.
  Problem 7
    - twig/extra-bundle is locked to version v3.6.0 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - twig/extra-bundle v3.6.0 requires symfony/framework-bundle ^4.4|^5.0|^6.0 -> found symfony/framework-bundle[v4.4.0, ..., v4.4.49, v5.0.0, ..., v5.4.22, v6.0.0, ..
., v6.2.10] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
  Problem 8
    - doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle is locked to version 3.4.4 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle 3.4.4 requires symfony/config ^3.4|^4.3|^5.0|^6.0 -> found symfony/config[v3.4.0, ..., v3.4.47, v4.3.0, ..., v4.4.44, v5.0.0, ..
., v5.4.21, v6.0.0, ..., v6.2.7] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
  Problem 9
    - Root composer.json requires symfony/debug-bundle ^6.2 -> satisfiable by symfony/debug-bundle[v6.2.0, v6.2.1, v6.2.5, v6.2.7].
    - symfony/debug-bundle[v6.2.0, ..., v6.2.7] require symfony/dependency-injection ^5.4|^6.0 -> found symfony/dependency-injection[v5.4.0, ..., v5.4.23, v6.0.0, ..., 
v6.2.10] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
  Problem 10
    - Root composer.json requires symfony/web-profiler-bundle ^6.2 -> satisfiable by symfony/web-profiler-bundle[v6.2.0, ..., v6.2.10].
    - symfony/web-profiler-bundle[v6.2.0, ..., v6.2.10] require symfony/config ^5.4|^6.0 -> found symfony/config[v5.4.0, ..., v5.4.21, v6.0.0, ..., v6.2.7] but these we
v5.0.0, ..., v5.4.23, v6.0.0, ..., v6.2.10] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
    - Root composer.json requires symfony/monolog-bundle ^3.1 -> satisfiable by symfony/monolog-bundle[v3.1.0, ..., v3.8.0].
```

And when I just do `composer update` I get this :

```
 Problem 1
    - sensio/framework-extra-bundle[v5.1.0, ..., v5.2.4] require symfony/config ^3.3|^4.0 -> found symfony/config[v3.3.0, ..., v3.4.47, v4.0.0, ..., v4.4.44] but these 
were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
    - sensio/framework-extra-bundle[v5.3.0, ..., v5.3.1] require symfony/config ^3.4|^4.2 -> found symfony/config[v3.4.0, ..., v3.4.47, v4.2.0, ..., v4.4.44] but these 
were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
    - sensio/framework-extra-bundle[v5.4.0, ..., v5.4.1] require symfony/config ^3.4|^4.3 -> found symfony/config[v3.4.0, ..., v3.4.47, v4.3.0, ..., v4.4.44] but these 
were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
    - sensio/framework-extra-bundle[v5.5.0, ..., v5.5.3] require symfony/config ^4.3|^5.0 -> found symfony/config[v4.3.0, ..., v4.4.44, v5.0.0, ..., v5.4.21] but these 
were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
    - sensio/framework-extra-bundle[v5.5.4, ..., v5.6.1] require symfony/config ^4.4|^5.0 -> found symfony/config[v4.4.0, ..., v4.4.44, v5.0.0, ..., v5.4.21] but these 
were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
    - Root composer.json requires sensio/framework-extra-bundle ^5.1 -> satisfiable by sensio/framework-extra-bundle[v5.1.0, ..., v5.6.1].

Use the option --with-all-dependencies (-W) to allow upgrades, downgrades and removals for packages currently locked to specific versions.
```

And finally, here's my `composer.json` content :

```
{
  "type": "project",
  "license": "proprietary",
  "require": {
    "php": "^8.2",
    "ext-ctype": "*",
    "ext-iconv": "*",
    "ext-json": "*",
    "ext-pdo": "*",
    "cboden/ratchet": "^0.4.3",
    "composer/package-versions-deprecated": "1.10.99.1",
    "doctrine/annotations": "^1.0",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "2.6.*",
    "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "^3.0",
    "doctrine/orm": "^2.7",
    "firebase/php-jwt": "^5.2",
    "gos/websocket-client": "^1.3",
    "mpdf/mpdf": "^8.0",
    "nelmio/cors-bundle": "^2.1",
    "onelogin/php-saml": "^3.5",
    "paragonie/sodium_compat": "^1.14",
    "phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock": "^5.2",
    "phpoffice/phpspreadsheet": "^1.18",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^5.1",
    "shuchkin/simplexlsx": "^1.0",
    "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "*",
    "symfony/apache-pack": "^1.0",
    "symfony/asset": "6.2.*",
    "symfony/console": "6.2.*",
    "symfony/dotenv": "6.2.*",
    "symfony/expression-language": "6.2.*",
    "symfony/flex": "^1.3.1",
    "symfony/form": "6.2.*",
    "symfony/framework-bundle": "6.2.*",
    "symfony/http-client": "6.2.*",
    "symfony/intl": "6.2.*",
    "symfony/mailer": "6.2.*",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.1",
    "symfony/process": "6.2.*",
    "symfony/property-access": "6.2.*",
    "symfony/property-info": "6.2.*",
    "symfony/security-bundle": "6.2.*",
    "symfony/serializer": "6.2.*",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^3.5",
    "symfony/translation": "6.2.*",
    "symfony/twig-bundle": "6.2.*",
    "symfony/validator": "6.2.*",
    "symfony/web-link": "6.2.*",
    "symfony/yaml": "6.2.*",
    "twig/extra-bundle": "^2.12|^3.0",
    "twig/twig": "^2.12|^3.0",
    "umulmrum/holiday": "^0.6.0"
  },
  "require-dev": {
    "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "^3.3",
    "phpstan/phpstan": "^1.10",
    "phpunit/php-invoker": "^3.1",
    "symfony/browser-kit": "^6.2",
    "symfony/css-selector": "^6.2",
    "symfony/debug-bundle": "^6.2",
    "symfony/maker-bundle": "^1.20",
    "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "^5.1",
    "symfony/stopwatch": "^6.2",
    "symfony/var-dumper": "^6.2",
    "symfony/web-profiler-bundle": "^6.2"
  },
  "config": {
    "preferred-install": {
      "*": "dist"
    },
    "sort-packages": true,
    "allow-plugins": {
      "symfony/flex": true
    }
  },
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "App\\": "src/"
    }
  },
  "autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
      "App\\Tests\\": "tests/"
    }
  },
  "replace": {
    "paragonie/random_compat": "2.*",
    "symfony/polyfill-ctype": "*",
    "symfony/polyfill-iconv": "*",
    "symfony/polyfill-php71": "*",
    "symfony/polyfill-php70": "*",
    "symfony/polyfill-php56": "*"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "auto-scripts": {
      "cache:clear": "symfony-cmd",
      "assets:install %PUBLIC_DIR%": "symfony-cmd"
    },
    "post-install-cmd": [
      "@auto-scripts"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
      "@auto-scripts"
    ]
  },
  "conflict": {
    "symfony/symfony": "*"
  },
  "extra": {
    "symfony": {
      "allow-contrib": false,
      "require": "6.2.*"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Create a new 6.2 project, add all third party packages and then use the resulting composer.json file as a guide.  It is actually quite amazing that you were able to move from 4.4 to 5.4 just by editing.

Comment: @Cerad you mean to get the target `composer.json` from a new symfony 6.2 project and then copy/paste to my current projet and then `composer update` ? (with all the necessary third party packages)

Comment: Yep.  Or at the very least you could compare the new with the old and maybe the problem will suddenly become obvious.  Over the versions Symfony has changed the way it uses composer.  And PHP itself is pushing out new versions which in turn impacts third party stuff.  Sometimes it's best to just build a new file from scratch.

Comment: You could try updating the "framework-extra-bundle" as well, seems 5.x does not support symfonfy 6. But also note that the bundle is no longer maintained anyway, so you should try to move away from it anyway.

Comment: `sensio/framework-extra-bundle` in v5 is not compatible with Symfony 6. Update it.